# Why is the default VSIX installation directory not in the default allowed VS locations?

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, vs-extensibility

As mentioned in other posts, by default VSIX extensions will install to the following directory matches and this cannot be changed:

```
%VSAPPDATA%\Extensions\
```

My question is: If that is the default location and is known, why are these locations not in the default list of allowed locations under Tools-->Options-->Environment-->Add-in Security?

The closest location is %VSAPPDATA%\Addins so this means that if you are developing VS Extensions you have only 2 options:

1. Create an MSI which deploys the required files to a known location and manually add that location in the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\\AutomationOptions\LookInFolders
2. Somehow notify the users of your extension to add this manually through VS.

Is this an oversight or am I missing something? I ended up going for option 1 above and can't help thinking it is overkill.

Comment: According to the [documentation here][1] all paths under %VSAPPDATA% are treated as safe locations by default.


 [1]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1326zbk3.aspx

Comment: That page only lists the tokens, e.g. %VSAPPDATA% and the paths they resolve to. Looking at 2 different machines both for VS 2010 and 2012 it is %VSAPPDATA%\Addins that is added by default rather than just %VSAPPDATA% (hence the question).